# CryptoJS Encryption and Decryption in UWP C#

Tags: c#, encryption, uwp

I have a video URL link which is encrypted using CryptoJS on a server and my job in my Universal Windows App in c# is to decrypt the sent content and get the original video URL link.

I have tried to use AES Decryption but still getting errors.
Below is the array that is generated when the URL is encrypted on the server

> Passphrase: e615242cd9498f2a38995d516bb5f8c819be91a4

Encrypted String: {"ct":"yA8RGCPPvX4f9QhIJ0ga2oOutxnUEcddh5iBQalPoAlNZgutVTefOdvwO54D7Bwl2eTr+i/u9/cDL6sVcvZ9+hXfr1eZ/sYjjKX0qSr+yPjA+CrQWeApBPVtS45JPCY8ekB2pZah8uqqtPpfeV5T8xHzrkJJbS0d+VqFhj1aqao/qWKdCaD6BK75QfnkBz0XzQd/ulK7saoLGO2t7LHhlg==","iv":"0fa9a8205ccb9894e416e8ba85bc4960","s":"60f24ca1a8380cac"}

Below is the code that requires an key and Iv and what to decrpyt

```
class AesEnDecryption
{
    // Key with 256 and IV with 16 length
    private string AES_Key = "";
    private string AES_IV = "";
    private IBuffer m_iv = null;
    private CryptographicKey m_key;

    public AesEnDecryption()
    {
        IBuffer key = Convert.FromBase64String(AES_Key).AsBuffer();
        m_iv = Convert.FromBase64String(AES_IV).AsBuffer();
        SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider provider = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesCbcPkcs7);
        m_key = provider.CreateSymmetricKey(key);
    }

    public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] input)
    {

        IBuffer bufferMsg = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(input), BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
        IBuffer bufferEncrypt = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(m_key, bufferMsg, m_iv);
        return bufferEncrypt.ToArray();
    }

    public string Decrypt(byte[] input)
    {
        IBuffer bufferDecrypt = CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(m_key, input.AsBuffer(), m_iv);

        string one = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bufferDecrypt.ToArray());
        return one;
    }

}
```

My issue is getting the required information from the encrypted CrytoJS array

Comment: Show your most recent code please.

Comment: I have edited and posted the code i have. Thank you

Comment: Since a passphrase is used (2nd parameter of `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt` is a string), key and IV are determined via a key derivation function (KDF). An implementation of this KDF (which probably needs to be adapted for UWP) can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/caspencer/1339719). Input parameters are `passphrase` (UTF8 encoded), `salt` (`s`, hex encoded), the digest (`MD5`) and an iteration count (`1`). Output parameters are key and IV (the latter is identical to the given `iv`). With key and IV the ciphertext (`ct`, Base64 encoded) can be decrypted.